# Cannot find resource when adding maven dependency to my maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm trying to add a maven dependency to my eclipse project.

The repository holding the dependency is here:
http://repo.franga2000.com/artifactory/webapp/browserepo.html?12

and I've followed the author's instructions, adding these entries to my pom.xml (full pom is here http://pastebin.com/Bku9r9DV):

```
    <repository>
        <id>fanciful-mvn-repo</id>
        <url>http://repo.franga2000.com/artifactory/public</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mkremins</groupId>
        <artifactId>fanciful</artifactId>
        <version>0.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

But in my coding, when I try:

```
import mkremins.fanciful.FancyMessage;
```

I get:

```
The import mkremins cannot be resolved
```

I have never had luck with maven dependencies... and now I'm following the author's instructions exactly, so I don't really know what's going wrong.

Comment: check if jar is loaded under folder .m2 ?

Comment: reload the maven, it's working fine when i tried that

Comment: @AdityaKamat - how? restart eclipse?

Comment: Are you trying talking about eclipse error or maven build error.
Eclipse might show error, till you execute a maven build and execute the eclipse:eclipse

Comment: @SaurabhJhunjhunwala - Eclipse error. Found solution tho, below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The POM setting is for resolving dependency for maven during build.
This doesn't mean that it will resolve it for you during coding.

For Resolving the dependency you need to download the jar(or any other) file and add it to your project's classpath.
If its a eclipse plugin the add it to your target platform and add that plugin into plugins dependency.

Comment: Added the .m2 / maven variable/extension thing to my build path and it works great now. Will need to remember that... 2 steps to add maven dependencies. thanks!

Comment: Well almost :(  Now at runtime, I get java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: mkremins.fanciful.FancyMessage. Looks like during execution it can't find the dependency .jar ... any ideas?

Comment: Runtime means-> Build time or after build when you are running your application?

Comment: Found the fix; really stupid of me. I'm now fully using maven and using a shaded jar to include necessary dependencies. :)